# .jpg image background clashes with html page white background while scrolling from top and bottom

Tags: html, css

When I scroll HTML page with background image a white background seen in the top of html page while scrolling.  Even after applying 100vh; height
In the top it can be seen that white background of html page
This one is hmtl code for contact page in which I set background image in CSS but I don't it's show white background at the top

Contact page html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> 
    <title>Rkfurnishingstore.com</title>
    <!-- Link to css-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <!-- Link mediaquery css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mediaquery.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/contact.css">
    <!-- Box Icon Import Css -->
    <link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.1.2/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
    <!-- Fav Icon -->
    <link rel="icon" href="image/mainfav.icon.png" type="image/png">
</head>

<body>
    <!-- Header -->
    <header>
        <div class="nav container">
            <!-- Menu Icon -->
            <div class="menu-icon">
                <div class="line1"></div>
                <div class="line2"></div>
                <div class="line3"></div>
            </div>
            <!-- Nav List -->
            <ul class="navbar">
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.html">Categories</a></li>
                <li><a href="index.html">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">Get In Touch</a></li>
            </ul>
            <!-- Logo -->
            <a href="#" class="logo">
                RK FURNISHING<span>.</span>
            </a>
            <!-- Nav Icons -->
            <div class="nav-icons">
                <i class='bx bx-user' id="user-icon"></i>
            </div>
            <!-- Login Form(User) -->
            <div class="login-form">
                <!-- Form -->
                <form action="">
                    <h2>Login To Continue</h2>
                    <input type="email" name="" id="" placeholder="Enter Your Email" required>
                    <input type="password" name="" id="" placeholder="Enter Your Password" required>
                    <a href="#">Forget Password?</a>
                    <input type="submit" value="Log In" class="btn">
                    <a href="#">Create account</a>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
    <section>
        <h2 class="gettouch">Get In Touch</h2>
        <h3> <a href="index.html" id="touchtohome">Home</a> / <span>Get Enquiry</span> </h3>
    </section>
    <div class="enquiry">
        <div class="form">
            <h3>ContactUs </h3>
            <p>We will get back to you asap</p>
            <input class="form-input" type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Enter Your name">
            <input class="form-input" type="text" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="Enter Your Phone">
            <input class="form-input" type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter Your email">
             <textarea class="form-input" name="text" id="text" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Ellaborate your Query"></textarea>
            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-dark">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>    
    <section>
        <iframe class="map"src="https://www.google.com/maps/d/embed?mid=1DOcC34s28_0j31bHdLexpEeGonBwL4w&hl=en&ehbc=2E312F" width="640" height="480"></iframe>
    </section>
    <!-- Copyright -->
    <div class="copyright">
        <p>&#169; www.rkfurnishingstore.com | All Right Reserved </p>
    </div>
    <!-- Link to JS -->
    <script src="Js/main.js"></script>
    
</body>

</html>
```

CSS For contact page

```
*{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    /* box-sizing: border-box;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center; */
}
header.shadow{
    background: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    transition: 0.3s;
    position: fixed;
}
html{
}
body{
    background: url("/image/contact/contact.jpg")no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size: cover;
}
.logo{
    color: white;
}
h2{
    color: white;
}
.gettouch{ 
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 4rem;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    cursor: pointer;
}
a:hover{
    background-color: var(--light-color);
}
h3{
    color: white;
    margin-top: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
#touchtohome{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: var(--main-color);

}
.enquiry{
    /* border: 2px solid orangered; */
    width: 52%;
    margin: auto;
    background: var(--light-color);
    border-radius: 15px;
    /* opacity: 0.9; */
}
.form{
    max-width: 62%;
    margin: 25px auto;
}
p{
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

.form-input{
    margin: 14px 0;
    padding: 5px 13px;
    width: 100%; 
    font-size: 19px;
    border: 2px solid grey;
    border-radius: 6px;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}
.map{
    border: 2px solid orangered;
    width: 70%;
    margin: 0 0 0 206px;
}
.copyright{
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: It will be better if you edit the question and put your code in a snippet then ensure it's working correctly. 

I tried your code but wasn't sure if it was working as it was supposed to. it confused me.

Comment: When you edit it, you will see a boxed icon **<>**.  Click on it and post your html and css there.